# String in VHDL Waveform

Tags: vhdl

How can I *print* a string in VHDL waveform?
[-> like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Cnr.png)

Comment: Make an output port whose type is a fixed length string, and assign to it.

Comment: Hi Sergiu, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read through the [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section, and ensure your question follows the guidelines, since that will give you most success getting answers in this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string is no different from other types of signals, so you can do like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture sim of tb is

  signal info : string(1 to 5);

begin

  process is
  begin
    info <= "Hello";
    wait for 1 us;
    info <= "VHDL ";
    wait for 1 us;
    info <= "world";
    wait for 1 us;
    info <= "!!!  ";
    wait for 1 us;
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

Simulation in [Intel Quartus ModelSim Starter Edition](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software/programmable/quartus-prime/model-sim.html) (free) then gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have this occur a lot when I make testbenches with labels.  Since string signals are bounded (fixed length), and VHDL is strongly typed, you must always pad as @morten-zilmer does in his code.  Signals are preferred since some simulators (Vivado) can't place variables in the waveforms, since they don't have defined event times as signals do.

I created a utility function below to help this, called `string_cast()`

```
SIGNAL testname: STRING(1 to 255);

FUNCTION string_cast(s: STRING; width: INTEGER := testname'LENGTH) RETURN STRING IS
  return s & (1 to width - s'LENGTH => ' '); -- pad spaces
END FUNCTION string_cast;
```

Now use as

```
testname <= string_cast("ShortName");
do_test1 actions...

testname <= string_cast("LongNameButNot255Chars"); 
do_test2 actions...
```

Hope this helps